# MongoDB Aggregate functions convert object array to string array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregate-functions

I have some documents in a collection. Every document has a challenge_id field. I want to map those document array into a string array. The final string array should consist of challenge ids from each document

input:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62c3e31931e7df585c39e4e1"),
    activity_id: ObjectId("62c3e31931e7df585c39e4df"),
    challenge_id: ObjectId("62bd543c3a3937000958f2dd"),
    status: "active",
    createdAt: ISODate("2022-07-05T07:07:05.823Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2022-07-05T07:07:05.823Z")
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62c3e33f299750585cc70b23"),
    activity_id: ObjectId("62c3e33e299750585cc70b21"),
    challenge_id: ObjectId("62bd543c3a3937000958f2dd"),
    status: "active",
    createdAt: ISODate("2022-07-05T07:07:43.612Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2022-07-05T07:07:43.612Z")
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62c3e359341e86585c65c714"),
    activity_id: ObjectId("62c3e359341e86585c65c712"),
    challenge_id: ObjectId("62bd543c3a3937000958f2dd"),
    status: "active",
    createdAt: ISODate("2022-07-05T07:08:09.409Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2022-07-05T07:08:09.409Z")
  }
]
```

output should looks like:

```
 ['62bd543c3a3937000958f2dd','62bd543c3a3937000958f2dd', '62bd543c3a3937000958f2dd' ]
```

Is it possible to do this with an aggregate function ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$group` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: 0, res: {$push: {$toString: "$challenge_id"}}}},
  {$project: {res: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iSM8yzvruED)